# Unable to restore native SQL Server .bak file to AWS RDS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, amazon-rds

I'm facing an issue with restoring a SQL Server native `.bak` file to my RDS instance running Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.5058.0 (X64) Enterprise Edition (64-bit).

The `.bak` file has been created from SQL Server running Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2100.60 (X64) Enterprise edition.

Actual problem is that when I try to run the below command,

```
exec msdb.dbo.rds_restore_database
          @restore_db_name='dbname',
          @s3_arn_to_restore_from='arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/dbbackupfile.bak'
```

Query completes in no time, but the database doesn't get created.

I thought it's an issue with the backup file and I tried restoring a sample backup file created in SQL Server 2012 (`adventureworks2012.bak`), it's still the same issue.

I made sure that the option group is set properly and also, IAM role to access my S3 bucket and file is in place.

Comment: "Query completes in no time, but the database doesn't get created."  - creation happens asynchronously, did you subsequently run `exec msdb.dbo.rds_task_status @db_name='dbname';`, which you should do periodically until the restore completes (or fails).

Comment: I ran it multiple times.. usually it would show the progress in the query execution output..the database size is also very small..so ideally it should show the progress and the database should show up, which never happened.

Comment: @Joe: Thanks for the help. it worked and i had to wait until the database creation gets completed and to know the status i ran the command you suggested.exec msdb.dbo.rds_task_status @db_name='dbname';

Answer (score 1):

@Joe: Thanks for the help. it worked and i had to wait until the database creation gets completed and to know the status i ran the command you suggested.exec msdb.dbo.rds_task_status @db_name='dbname';

Cant thank you enough..

Comment: Glad it helped.  I suggest you accept this answer to help others that may encounter the same issue.